# Changing Java PriorityQueue to a Max PQ

Tags: java, priority-queue, standard-library

The Priority Queue implementation in the Java standard library appears to be a min Priority Queue which I found somewhat confusing. In order to turn it into a max one I created a custom comparator object.

```
Comparator<Integer> cmp = new Comparator<Integer>()
{
    public int compare( Integer x, Integer y )
    {
        return y - x;
    }
};
```

I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution. Essentially I wan't a generic priority queue that could be used to implement Dijkstras etc. I didn't even realise there would be ones which operated in reverse :/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use Java's `Collections.reverseOrder()` comparator.

[Java Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28%29)

Answer (score 35):

Here is a code snippet using `Collections.reverseOrder()`-

```
    PriorityQueue<Integer> maxPQ = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(20,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

You also need to provide the initial capacity of the Priority Queue (20 here) along with the Comparator.

Comment: Java 8 adds a constructor that takes just a Comparator (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), so if you're using Java 8 you don't have to provide the initial capacity.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what you mean by elegant but when I want a PQ implemented like a MaxHeap (used in Dijkstra's) I just use an inline comparator constructor.

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> PQ= new PriorityQueue<Integer>(20, new Comparator<Integer>(){
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2){
                return o2 - o1;
            }
        });
```

It's simple enough for anytime I'm looking for something simple and only want to use the Comparator once.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing comparator you could create a generic inversing comparator.

```
public class InverseComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    private final Comparator<T> delegate;

    public InverseComparator(Comparator<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public int compare(T x, T y) {
        return delegate(y, x);
    }
}
```